# simplecaptcha-1.2.1.jar (Timeout issue)

Tags: java, simplecaptcha

We are using simplecaptcha-1.2.1.jar in our project. Captcha values expires very quickly but i cannot see specific time duration configured anywhere.

what is the maximum time limit for simple captcha to expire?
Is the time configurable ?